# How to resize root Volume Group

Tags: partition, lvm, disk, volume

How Can I reduce size of root volume group?

```
 /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00
```

I just have SSH access to Linux host.

Comment: What file system is it? What operating system?

Answer (score 1):

Root VG? You mean your root LV?

If so, that's impossible to shrink while root is online, (you could fall back to ramfs if you have physical access).

The only way to do it, is boot from an external media (or partition), and resize the root partition with `resize2fs` with `lvresize`

Comment: You can extend a logical volume if there's a mounted FS on it, but that won't enlarge the file system. You would  have to do it after. Many FS allow to do it while mounted so the statement above is false. To reduce the size of a LV, you need first to reduce the FS on it (if there is a FS). Fewer filesystems support being reduced while mounted but a few (like `btrfs`) do. `resize2fs` can only resize ext2,3,4 file systems.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Many filesystems allow live enlargement, but this question is about reducing the size.

Comment: Yes @Gilles, as I said, `btrfs` (now becoming the new standard FS for Linux) and a few other filesystems allow reducing live. And I was pointing out that the statement "you can't resize a live FS" was false.